# Doubletap in Ipad using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

My task is to have a alert from ipad when i doubletap on my content.And i used this code to check my doubletap

```
(function($){
// Determine if we on iPhone or iPad
var isiOS = false;
var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if(agent.indexOf('iphone') >= 0 || agent.indexOf('ipad') >= 0){
       isiOS = true;
}

$.fn.doubletap = function(onDoubleTapCallback, onTapCallback, delay){
    var eventName, action;
    delay = delay == null? 500 : delay;
    eventName = isiOS == true? 'touchend' : 'click';

    $(this).bind(eventName, function(event){
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var lastTouch = $(this).data('lastTouch') || now + 1 /** the first time this will make delta a negative number */;
        var delta = now - lastTouch;
        clearTimeout(action);
        if(delta<500 && delta>0){
            if(onDoubleTapCallback != null && typeof onDoubleTapCallback == 'function'){
                onDoubleTapCallback(event);
            }
        }else{
            $(this).data('lastTouch', now);
            action = setTimeout(function(evt){
                if(onTapCallback != null && typeof onTapCallback == 'function'){
                    onTapCallback(evt);
                }
                clearTimeout(action);   // clear the timeout
            }, delay, [event]);
        }
        $(this).data('lastTouch', now);
    });
};)(jQuery);
```

And i call this code from my page

```
$(".selector").doubletap(
/** doubletap-dblclick callback */
function(event){
    alert('double-tap');
},
/** touch-click callback (touch) */
function(event){
    alert('single-tap');
},
/** doubletap-dblclick delay (default is 500 ms) */
400);
```

it works in my desktop.but when i open it in ipad it didn't work properly.please suggest me some solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i used this code.

```
var elm1 = document.getElementById('test1');
var elm2 = document.getElementById('test2');
var timeout;
var lastTap = 0;
elm1.addEventListener('touchend', function(event) {
var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
var tapLength = currentTime - lastTap;
clearTimeout(timeout);
if (tapLength < 500 && tapLength > 0) {
    elm2.innerHTML = 'Double Tap';
    event.preventDefault();
} else {
    elm2.innerHTML = 'Single Tap';
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        elm2.innerHTML = 'Single Tap (timeout)';
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }, 500);
}
lastTap = currentTime;
});
```